# Is There Any Way to Get Shared Link Count in Certain Period of Time Using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get share count for link shared in Facebook during certain period of time. The links are all links to my website. I'm thinking of using the Facebook Graph API - insights, do daily checking and save the share count.

From graph explorer I get the insights/domain_stories result and it has this:

```
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 0, 
      "end_time": "2015-03-21T07:00:00+0000"
    },
```

Reading at the metric description I thought I would get detail like which page in my website that's been shared.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights#availmetrics

Is there any way to get that kind of information?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately the `/?id={url}` endpoint doesn't provide time period data.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/url

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm looking into using domain insights, hoping I can get daily count and save them.

Comment: Yes, but there is no metric for that, respectively `domain_stories` doesn't return the link itself which was shared IMHO...

Comment: I'm new to facebook graph api so I thought there's something I might miss but I guess you're right, no way to do that for now. Thanks, @Tobi